# Can I delete the record where cursor is pointing not using SQL?

Tags: python, sql, database, pymysql

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='123456', db='jd', charset='utf8')
cur = conn.cursor() 
sql = "select * from user where username = 'XXX'"
cur.execute(sql)
```

After this piece of code has been executed,the cursor should pointing to the record I've selected.

What I want to do is get one record,handle something with the data in the record,and then detele the record.

I know there's `cur.fetchone()`,`cur.fetchall()` methods in Python.I my opnion,since the cursor can fetchone record,why there is no `cur.deteleOne()` or `cur.delete_previousOne()` function?

Answer (score 0):

A cursor points at a row of data returned by a `SELECT` statement, which is not the same thing as an actual row in a table.

A SELECT statement can perform many manipulations on its results, such as joining two or more tables together, ordering the results by a specific field, gathering only distinct values for a specific field, etc.

In the course of performing these manipulations, it is not always possible to maintain a link back to specific table rows.  You can even use the `SELECT AS` statement to fetch data that isn't part of *any* table; deleting such a "row" would clearly be impossible.

Is there a reason you don't want to use sql to delete the rows?

Comment: Your answer has inspired me! My problem is ,except the select as circumstance,why don’t the designer of the database connector create a pointer (like pointer in C or C++)，so we can use the pointer to update,delete etc？